# "dronekit-sitl waiting for connection..." But what am I to do next?

Tags: dronekit-python

[I have installed it. But what to do next?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euwGx.jpg)
MavProxy application doesn't respond to commands or am I doing something wrong over here.
In short, someone please guide me through connecting simulated vehicle with mission planner. I know it is very rudimentary but please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect dronekit-sitl to Mission Planner simply just set the connection setting (at the top right) to TCP then click the connect button and set the remote IP 127.0.0.1 and remote port to 5760. Like in this picture:

1. [image: Set connection type]
2. [image: Set remote IP]
3. [image: Set remote Port]

And you should be connected to the dronekit-sitl, the developer actually specify the connection setup at their docs [Link](http://python.dronekit.io/develop/sitl_setup.html).

---

But I recommend you to not use the dronekit-sitl if you are using it to develop program using dronekit. Just use the original SITL from Ardupilot site [Link](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/sitl-simulator-software-in-the-loop.html). Why ? because the dronekit-sitl is limited to the version 3.3 firmware (Right now the latest firmware is 3.6) and you can't do advanced testing with it (Like simulate LIDAR, Wind simulation, even connecting your SITL to 3D Simulator).

A tips from me is if you want to develop your program in Windows and use the Mission Planner as GCS you can enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and install Ubuntu to the WSL and follow the SITL setup on Linux guide [Link](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/setting-up-sitl-on-linux.html).

OR just use Ubuntu to develop your program and use APM Planner as your GCS [Link](http://ardupilot.org/planner2/) or just install Mission Planner on Ubuntu using WINE/Crossover (This is the option I use right now).

Comment: I did that and it does not work in APM Planner. APM2 and Mission Planner are the same, right?

Comment: It is the same for their core function, but Mission Planner feel more polished than APM Planner